# R unable to revalue - unable to translate to native encoding

Tags: r, plyr

I have recently scraped some data from widget sports to use in my fantasy football league. Some of the player names have been recorded as weird symbols. When I try and rename the player names using plyr::revalue i get an error saying that 'the values aren't present in x' even though i have copied them directly from the console or the View(f). Any help would be greatly appreciated. Code below:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)
library(plyr)



url <- "https://widgets.sports-reference.com/wg.fcgi?css=1&site=fb&url=%2Fen%2Fcomps%2F9%2Fstats%2FPremier-League-Stats&div=div_stats_standard"


f <- url %>% 
  xml2::read_html() %>%
  rvest::html_nodes('table') %>%
  html_table() %>%
  .[[1]]


names(f)<-c("RK", "Player", "Nation", "Pos", "Squad" ,"Age", "Born" ,"MP", "Starts", "Min","90s", "Goals", "Assists", "Non-pen_goals",
 "Pens_scored", "Pen_attempts", "Yellow_cards", "Red_cards", "G_P90","A_P90" ,"G+A_P90", "G-pen_P90", "G+A-pen_P90", "xG", "npxG",
 "xA", "npxG+xA", "xG_P90", "xA_P90", "xG+xA_p90", "npxG_P90", "npxG+xA_P90", "Matches" )



f$Player<-revalue(f$Player, c("Ã\u0087aÄ\u009flar SÃ¶yÃ¼ncÃ¼" = "Çaglar Söyüncü",   
                              "Ã\u0089rik Lamela" = "Erik Lamela",
                              "Ä°lkay GÃ¼ndoÄ\u009fan" = "Ilkay Gündogan",
                              "Å\u0081ukasz FabiaÅ\u0084ski" = "Lukasz Fabianski",
                              "Abdoulaye DoucourÃ©" = "Abdoulaye Doucouré", 
                              "Adama TraorÃ©" = "Adama Traoré",
                              "AdriÃ¡n" = "Alisson Ramses Becker",
                              "AndrÃ© Gomes‡" = "André Filipe Tavares Gomes",
                              "Antonio RÃ¼diger" = "Antonio Rüdiger",
                              "Ayoze PÃ©rez" = "Ayoze Pérez",
                              "Bertrand TraorÃ©" = "Bertrand Traoré",
                              "CÃ©dric Soares‡" = "Cédric Soares",
                              "CÃ©sar Azpilicueta" = "César Azpilicueta",
                              "CaoimhÃ­n Kelleher" = "Caoimhin Kelleher", 
                              "Cheikhou KouyatÃ©" = "Cheikhou Kouyaté", 
                              "Davinson SÃ¡nchez" = "Davinson Sánchez", 
                              "Davy PrÃ¶pper" = "Davy Pröpper",
                              "Emiliano MartÃ­nez" = "Emiliano Martínez",
                              "FÃ¡bio Silva" = "Fabio Silva",
                              "Fabian SchÃ¤r" = "Fabian Schär",
                              "Federico FernÃ¡ndez" = "Federico Fernández",
                              "Fernando MarÃ§al" = "Fernando Marçal",
                              "FerrÃ¡n Torres" = "Ferran Torres",
                              "Gylfi SigurÃ°sson" = "Gylfi Sigurdsson", 
                              "HÃ©ctor BellerÃ­n" = "Héctor Bellerín",
                              "HÃ©lder Costa" = "Hélder Wander Sousa de Azevedo e Costa",
                              "JÃ³hann Berg GuÃ°mundsson"= "Johann Berg Gudmundsson",
                              "JaÃ¯ro Riedewald" = "Jairo Riedewald", 
                              "James RodrÃ­guez" = "James Rodríguez",
                              "JoÃ£o Cancelo" = "João Pedro Cavaco Cancelo",
                              "JoÃ£o Moutinho" ="João Filipe Iria Santos Moutinho",
                              "JoÃ£o VirgÃ­nia" ="João Virgínia",
"JoÃ«l Matip" = "Joel Matip",
"JoÃ«l Veltman" = "Joël Veltman",
"JosÃ© Izquierdo" = "José Izquierdo",
"Luka MilivojeviÄ\u0087" = "Luka Milivojevic",
"Martin Ã\u0098degaard" = "Martin Ødegaard",
"Martin DÃºbravka" = "Martin Dubravka",
"MatÄ\u009bj Vydra" = "Matej Vydra",
"Mateo KovaÄ\u008diÄ\u0087" = "Mateo Kovacic",
"Miguel AlmirÃ³n" = "Miguel Almirón",
"N'Golo KantÃ©" = "N'Golo Kanté", 
"NÃ©lson Semedo" = "Nélson Cabral Semedo", 
"Naby KeÃ¯ta" = "Naby Keita", 
"Nathan AkÃ©" = "Nathan Aké",
"Nemanja MatiÄ\u0087" = "Nemanja Matic", 
"Nicolas PÃ©pÃ©" = "Nicolas Pépé", 
"Pablo HernÃ¡ndez" = "Pablo HernÃ¡ndez", 
"Pablo MarÃ" = "Pablo Marí", 
"Pascal GroÃ\u009f" = "Pascal Groß",
"Pierre HÃ¸jbjerg" = "Pierre-Emile Højbjerg",
"RaÃºl JimÃ©nez" = "Raúl Jiménez",
"RÃºben Dias" = "Rúben Santos Gato Alves Dias",
"RÃºben Neves" = "Rúben Diogo da Silva Neves",
"RÃºben Vinagre" = "Rúben Gonçalo da Silva Nascimento Vinagre",
"RÃºnar Alex RÃºnarsson" = "Rúnar Alex Rúnarsson",
"Rayan AÃ¯t Nouri" = "Rayan Ait Nouri",
"Robert SÃ¡nchez" = "Robert Sánchez",
"Romain SaÃ¯ss" = "Romain Saïss",
"Rui PatrÃ­cio" = "Rui Pedro dos Santos Patrício",
"SÃ©amus Coleman" = "Seamus Coleman",
"SaÃ¯d Benrahma" = "Saïd Benrahma", 
"Sadio ManÃ©" = "Sadio Mané",
"Sead KolaÅ¡inac" = "Sead Kolasinac", 
"Sergio ReguilÃ³n" = "Sergio Reguilón",
"Thiago AlcÃ¡ntara" = "Thiago Alcántara do Nascimento",
"TomÃ¡Å¡ SouÄ\u008dek" = "Tomas Soucek",
"TrÃ©zÃ©guet" = "Mahmoud Ahmed Ibrahim Hassan",
"Victor LindelÃ¶f" = "Victor Lindelöf",
"VladimÃ­r Coufal" = "Vladimir Coufal"

))
```

***Edit***
If i just try to revalue the first name i get this error message: 'The following `from` values were not present in `x`: Ã<U+0087>aÄ<U+009F>lar SÃ¶yÃ¼ncÃ¼
Warning message:
unable to translate 'Ã<U+0087>aÄ<U+009F>lar SÃ¶yÃ¼ncÃ¼' to native encoding'

```
f$Player<-revalue(f$Player, c("Ã\u0087aÄ\u009flar SÃ¶yÃ¼ncÃ¼" = "Çaglar Söyüncü"))
```

Comment: This is not an answer, but I think you want to load `plyr` befor `dplyr`, not after. I don't if there are still issues with it (I had seen some in the past). It isn't likely the reason for your issue, it is just something I noticed.

Comment: Thanks steveb. Done this now but same issue

Comment: Yeah, I didn't expect it to fix this issue, just potentially avoid other issues later.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to remove all the problem symbols using:

```
 f$Player<-iconv(f$Player, from = "UTF-8", to = "ASCII", sub = "")
```

I will now have to retype the player names but should work now hopefully.